# How to get number from website via BeautifulSoup python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a link to a site where I get a certain number when I enter a phone number, I need this number to be displayed in int format so that I can implement an

```
if (here is a variable that stores the received number from the site) > 0
```

Here is what i tried to do:

```
g_index = input(gr+"[+] введите номер пользователя : "+re)
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=g_index, first_name="custom_first_name", last_name="custom_last_name")
result = client(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
if not client.get_entity(g_index):
    g_index = input(gr+"[+] у данного номера нет аккаунта в телеграмм\nпожалуйтса, введите следующий номер : "+re)
else:
    url = 'http://******.**/ocean/oceansite_balance.php?to=%s' % (g_index)
    resp = req.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.p)
```

But in the console, instead of the number `0`, the following is displayed: `< p > 0 < / p >` accordingly, I cannot work with this, since I need an int number, not a string.

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

> following is displayed: < p > 0 < / p > ... since I need an int number, not a string

Simply call `.text` or better [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) on the object:

```
int(soup.p.string.strip())
```

or

```
int(soup.p.text.strip())
```

or [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) with parameters to strip or separate contents:

```
int(soup.p.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p> 0 </p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

int(soup.p.get_text(strip=True)) > 0
```

Will result in:

```
False
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer, could you clarify for me? How exactly to use your code?

Comment: Could you describe more specific what is not clear? Would be great. While `soup.p` gives you an object and you like to get its text, simply call the methode that will do it for and `int()` convert it to integer. may also take a read of the linked docs.

Comment: Thank you! And could you help me some more? I would like to check the received number, but I can not pick up the variable correctly.
It is necessary that the resulting number pass through if (the variable where the number is stored int) > 0: #code

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Also take a short read of: How to create [mcve] and try to provide HTML, url and expected output, what makes it easier to reproduce your issue and clarify.  Thanks

Comment: I already figured it out myself, the variable is not needed there, thank you very much for your contribution to my project